# Youtube is putting big interior borders on its thumbnails for me

Tags: wordpress, youtube

Everything was working fine last night, aside from the flukiness that YouTube tends to inject into things when you start working with custom thumbnails. This problem presents itself in IE, Chrome, FF, on multiple machines, and the website in question is https://diyreception.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYW7G.jpg   <--- this is a screenshot of the issue. I thought that I was doing things pretty straightforwardly, and it was all working 24 hours ago. Now it's all wonky.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, it appears that the css background-size is set to contain instead of cover.  I don't know a fix yet but when I do I'll comment.

Comment: if you are doing direct embeds changing /embed/ to /v/ in the url fixes it.

Comment: /v/ fixes it in Chrome and Firefox is still good, but IE11 now has a white border on two sides, so not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to uncheck a box within Wordpress's settings ... Settings, Media, uncheck "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)"